# Eclipse: "Delete" button wants to delete my source files instead of code.. why?

Tags: eclipse

I am programming in Eclipse and the "Delete" button wants to delete my source files instead of code.

and if i want to use Ctrl+A to select all my code it is selects all the files in package explorer...

All the shortcuts i want to use in my code it is takes effect on PackageExplorer. 
Everything like ctrl +c , ctrl +v , delete button, or ctrl +a

Please dont come solutions like "click on your code" because at least i tried that before asking.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. Seems some of my source files are in archive and read-only mode.

Executing command `attrib -r -a /s /d` solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Click and focus on your code window. Your focus currently is on PackageExplorer.

Comment: Well i tried clicking first, then asked. No matter what i do, i can only write to source but if i use some shortcuts or delete button it is takes effect in package explorer beneath my files.